# Create procedure to execute query in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

Maybe it's not new case, but I'm stack about it. This is the procedure that I use to run query, it run normally in MySQL, but not in PostgreSQL and I don't know how to do that. The procedure(in MySQL) looks like :

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE runstatement(IN statement TEXT)
BEGIN 
  SET @s = statement; 
  IF LENGTH(@s) <> 0 THEN PREPARE stmt FROM @s; 
    EXECUTE stmt; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
  END IF; 
END
```

The questions:

1. How do I convert it to PostgreSQL version?
2. How do I call this procedure(runstatement) when I need it in another procedure? In MySQL I know as `CALL runstatement(param)`.

Thanks for each reply. I'm new in database programming especially PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This technique is named *dynamic SQL*. PLpgSQL has `EXECUTE` statement for this case. Probably is useless to write special function just for this, because `EXECUTE` is one line command.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION runstatement(statement TEXT)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  IF statement <> '' THEN
    EXECUTE statement;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Probably test on empty string is bad design. This case should not to be. `Assert` is better there.

This function can be called:

```
SELECT runstatement(''); -- outside plpgsql
```

or

```
PERFORM runstatement('') -- inside plpgsql
```

See [related part](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in documentation.

Comment: Thank's @Pavel Stehule. Yes, you are right, only one line, It can run with `PERFORM` inside of plpgsql.

I will up vote for useful explain for anyone who new in database programming like me.

Answer (score 0):

how to create stored procedures in postgresql 11 and dbconnection with .net.
if we have older version we don't have procedures. now we have procedures in postgresql version 11. This is new postgresql version 11.

```
        -- DROP PROCEDURE public.sp_lite_web_login_conn(text, character varying, xml, xml);
        -- call sp_lite_web_login_conn('PG_LOAD', 'LG570', 'one', 'two')
        CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.sp_lite_web_login_conn(
                        p_flag text,
                        p_site character varying,
                        INOUT result_one refcursor,
                        INOUT result_two refcursor)
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
        AS $BODY$         
        BEGIN
              open result_one FOR SELECT 'NOT_OK' AS STATUS;
              open result_two FOR SELECT 'NOT_OK' AS STATUS;                                       
        END;
        $BODY$;
```

the below procedures refcursor based select query.

```
           public DataSet executeSelectQuery_POST_PROC(string _query, NpgsqlParameter[] sqlParameter)
                {
                    NpgsqlConnection npg_conn1 = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
                    try
                    {
                        npg_conn1.Open();
                        NpgsqlTransaction tran = npg_conn1.BeginTransaction();
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(_query, npg_conn1);
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameter);
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        NpgsqlDataAdapter da;
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (NpgsqlParameter parm in sqlParameter)
                        {
                            if (parm.NpgsqlDbType == NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor)
                            {
                                string parm_val = string.Format("FETCH ALL IN \"{0}\"", parm.Value.ToString());
                                da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(parm_val.Trim().ToString(), npg_conn1);
                                ds.Tables.Add(parm_val);
                                da.Fill(ds.Tables[i]);
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                        tran.Commit();
                        return ds;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        npg_conn1.Close();
                    }
                }

user control

  public DataSet db_validation(string flag, string site)
        {
            string query = string.Format(@"call sp_lite_web_login_conn('" + flag + "','" + site + "',@first_tbl,@second_tbl)");
            NpgsqlParameter[] sqlParameters = new NpgsqlParameter[4];
            sqlParameters[0] = new NpgsqlParameter("@p_flag", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlParameters[0].Value = Convert.ToString(flag);
            sqlParameters[1] = new NpgsqlParameter("@p_site", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlParameters[1].Value = Convert.ToString(site);
            //
            sqlParameters[2] = new NpgsqlParameter("@first_tbl", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor);
            sqlParameters[2].Value = Convert.ToString("first_tbl");
            sqlParameters[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
            sqlParameters[2].NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor;
            sqlParameters[3] = new NpgsqlParameter("@second_tbl", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor);
            sqlParameters[3].Value = Convert.ToString("second_tbl");
            sqlParameters[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
            sqlParameters[3].NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor;

            return conn.executeSelectQuery_POST_PROC(query, sqlParameters);
        }
```

Comment: This sample works correctly.. and tested by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a procedure in PL/pgSQL or SQL language.

For example, you create `test` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  num INTEGER
);
```

Then, you insert the row whose `num` is `2` as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (2);
```

Now, you can create `my_proc()` PL/pgSQL procedure which adds `value` to `num` and returns `value` to the caller as shown below:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc(IN value INTEGER, OUT result INTEGER)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE test SET num = num + value;
  SELECT num INTO result FROM test;
END;
$$;
```

Or, you can create `my_proc()` SQL procedure which adds `value` to `num` and returns `value` to the caller as shown below:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc(IN value INTEGER, OUT result INTEGER)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
UPDATE test SET num = num + value;
SELECT num FROM test;
$$;
```

Then, you can call `my_proc(3, 10)` with [CALL statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-call.html), then `5` is returned and `3` is added to `num` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# CALL my_proc(3, 10);
 result
--------
      5
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT num FROM test;
 num
-----
   5
(1 row)
```