# Converting MSSQL Stored Procedure with more than 80 columns to PostgreSQL with minimal changes

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

I have been working on this project which has MSSQL as DB provider, but due to some movements, my client wants this Database shifted from MSSQL to Postgres.

I am new to Postgres and today I found that in order to return table data I need to write [functions instead of SPs with certain syntax different from MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52090225/9144250)

I have some procedures in MSSQL which has around 80 columns.
It is getting tedius for me to write: `returns table(col1 col1_type, ....80 times)` statement ([syntax found in docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)) for all procedures.

**EDIT**: Also the most of the procedures are not returning exact columns as any table I have in my DB, so I believe I cannot use `returns setof tablename`.

I want to know if there is any other way to convert these procedures where I can skip this `returns table` statement. Or any offline converter which can do it for me?

Attaching dummy sp to understand how I am writing psql functions:

```
DROP function if exists GetUsers();

CREATE or replace function GetUsers()
returns table(Id varchar, Username varchar, Email varchar, Role varchar)
language 'plpgsql'
as $$
declare
BEGIN

return QUERY SELECT u.Id, u.Username, u.Email, ur."Role"
FROM Users u
JOIN UserRoleMapping urm
ON u.Id = urm.Id
JOIN UserRole ur
ON urm.RoleId = ur.Id;

end;$$;

select * from GetUsers();
```

I am using PostgreSQL 13.0.

Comment: If the query returns (all) columns from one table, you can write `returns setof tablename`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no sir, query inside procedures has joins and nested queries, so columns are different than table schema. Also, some sps are returning more than 1 tables

Comment: Why not just create views?

Comment: right, makes sense, can I write view name in the place of tablename like `returns setof viewname` ? also what about procedures returning more than 1 tables?

Comment: No, just ditch the functions - at least if they are all as simple as the one shown. Just wrap the query into a view instead of wrapping it with a function

Comment: No, I just added one function as example for better understanding, although I can eliminate basic procedures and convert them into views, I will still be left with around 10 procedures which returns multiple tables with 80+ columns

Comment: Thanks for the help, let me know if there are any alternative for these remaining procedures, or else I will continue writing it with all columns as a last option